# How to get the ID of the parent of an element in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, element, parent

In the code below:

```
   angular.element(element).parent()
```

How can I access the ID of the parent? When if I do this:

```
   console.log(angular.element(element).parent())
```

the console gives me below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.attr()`/`.prop()` method

```
angular.element(element).parent().attr('id')
```